# respond.min.js, line 5 character 746, access is denied , in IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3, respond.js

actually i am testing my site in IE8 using bootstrap3. I used these lines of code.

```
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
```

When I was debugging the code,  IE8 reflects the error at **c.open("GET",a,!0)** , how can I solve it , what is the issue ????

Comment: Are you runing page from your hard-drive?

Comment: This is the path i am using  C:\Users\...\..\..\Login1.html

Comment: Then it's a permission problem. IE8 blocks script, loaded from oss.maxcdn.com, from trying to read contents of your harddrive (some css file I believe)

Comment: Try using some lightweight http server, I prefer f.e. Netbeans, it has built in browser

Comment: @shreyansh Can either of the answers to your question be accepted as correct? Or maybe you could provide an alternate answer.

Answer (score 1):

When using bootstrap and IE8, you must run you html from a server to avoid a security issue as stated by @jevgenig. When testing locally, you can use `localhost` as a substitute.

I also recommend wrapping these scripts in IE specific comments in your header.

```
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: You should put respond.js in head tag so that media queries work before the page DOM gets loaded to prevent visual glitches.Otherwise the contents will once load without media queries and will again apply new styles when the js is loaded

Answer (score 0):

to run respond.js you need a localhost. This will solve you problem.